# Delegation on a class in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a delegation/initialization problem I can't seem to solve. Basically I have a storyboard with a few View controllers. Inside the storyboard there is this "View controller" which consists of a UITableview that I have connected with a DeviceListViewController class so that it populates the information. In here I have declared the following protocol:

```
protocol DeviceListViewControllerDelegate: UIAlertViewDelegate {
    var connectionMode:ConnectionMode { get }
    func connectPeripheral(peripheral:CBPeripheral, mode:ConnectionMode)
    func stopScan()
    func startScan()
}
```

and inside the class itself I have a init method like this (which is probably wrong but I didn't know what else I could do at this point):

```
 convenience init(aDelegate: DeviceListViewControllerDelegate) {

    self.init()

    self.delegate = aDelegate
}
```

Then there is this second class that is not attached to any view controller called BLEMainViewController. It should be a singleton handling all the bluetooth actions. This means I should be able to delegate some stuff between DevicelistViewController and BLEMainViewController.

In the BLEMainViewController I have inherited the DeviceListViewControllerDelegate:

```
class BLEMainViewController: NSObject, DeviceListViewControllerDelegate {

    var deviceListViewController:DeviceListViewController!
    var delegate: BLEMainViewControllerDelegate?
    static let sharedInstance = BLEMainViewController()

}

override init() {
    super.init()
    //        deviceListViewController.delegate = self
    deviceListViewController = DeviceListViewController(aDelegate: self)
}
```

The problem is that BLEMainViewController is not attached to any View Controller (and it shouldn't IMO) but it needs to be initialized as a singleton in order to handle all the BLE actions. Can anyone point me in the right direction (with an example preferably) on how to work around this?

[image: Setup]

Comment: so why have you made it a view controller?

Comment: Well, I needed to do that in order to show Alerts etc but I just figured that is actually really stupid to do :/

Comment: I made a normal class of it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply used wrong code architecture.

The BLEManager is a shared-instance, you can call it from everywhere, set it properties, and call its methods.
Its can delegate your view-controller with any predefine events you will add to its protocol and provide proper implementation

Here is some code, hope it helps

```
protocol BLEManagerDelegate{
    func bleManagerDidStartScan(manager : BLEManager)
}

class BLEManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = BLEManager()

    var delegate: BLEManagerDelegate?
    var devices : [AnyObject] = []

    func startScan(){
        delegate?.bleManagerDidStartScan(self)
        //do what ever
    }

    func stopScan(){

    }
}
```

Comment: So my I got the DeviceListViewController and its protocol. What my BLEManager should do is handle those protocol methods. ( so I need to delegate these to the BLEManager ) But I can't figure from your code how to set the delegation properly